# Android -- What is a clean, simple way to load a png with transpent regions into a bitmap

Tags: android, image

Ive been perusing the related answers, and nothing seems to be working as advertised, probably my fault. I can't imagine it would take more than 3 or 4 lines to get the job done. Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

BitmapFactory.decodeStream() or related APIs on that class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Comment: That's what I was using. The transparent png sections aren't transparent, at least not in ogl.

Comment: I can assure you that the Bitmap loaded here has the correct transparency information, provided that you haven't set the load options to force a color space that doesn't support transparency.  How to use a transparent bitmap with OpenGL is a *very* different question; I can't help you with that off-hand, and if you want to have a better chance at finding help I suggest posting a question specifically about that.